# CGContext is nil for specific image buffer sizes

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-graphics, cgcontext

When I tried to create CGContext from CVImageBuffer with below code

```
func drawImage(image:CGImage, sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer){
    
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
        
        return
    }
    
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: .zero))
    
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
    
    let context = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer),
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer),
                            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                            bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue).union(.byteOrder32Little).rawValue)
    
    context?.draw(image, in: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 200, height: 200))) // sometime context is nil here
    
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: .zero))
}
```

CGContext is nil with below Error

> CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 8640
> for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components,
> kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst.

**Note: This happens only with specific image buffer size like 4k, etc. And 1080p and 720p works fine.**

Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: how do u call pass data to ```pixelBuffer```? How do u create the ```imageBuffer```?

Comment: @uditha Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting the pixelbuffer to CIImage with `imageWithCVPixelBuffer` and convert it to CGImage. May be the pixelbuffer contains YUV data instead of RGBA.